Extracting clean logs from application overwriting itslog file without truncating it first on Linux
I have a closed source legacy application with a very interesting behavior:
It uses a fixed size log file of N megabytes and when the file is full it reset "seek" pointer to 0 and start overwriting the file from the beginning WITHOUT truncating it.
So after it growed up to N megabytes, you end up having last application logs in the middle of the file, tailed bw previous set of N megabytes logs...
Obviously modyfing the application is not possible, so I have no idea what I could do to workaround this issue and be able to import these log entries into a syslog server.
I'm especially annoyed by the fact current newest logs entries are not at the end of the file which kind of sounds like a definitive blocker to me.
Options I might see here are:

Being somehow able to detect current offset the application is writing on, and following this to track new linesw but I have no idea how to do that
Dirty patching C code using a LD_PRELOAD to ensure log file is never overwritten or truncate is done first so I can tail it.

Any suggestions?

It might be possible with ptrace. To verify this, have a look at an strace of the application process while it logs something.

Using LD_PRELOAD should work.
Let's try an example (assuming I understood your explanation of the application behavior):
// app.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const size_t MAX_LOG_SIZE = 1024;

int main()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("LOG", "w");
  int counter = 0;
  while (1) {
    fprintf(fp, "Log line %8d\n", ++counter);
    fflush(fp);
    if (ftell(fp) > MAX_LOG_SIZE) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Log size exceeded, rewinding\n");
      rewind(fp);
    }
    if ((counter % 10) == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Counter: %d\n", counter);
    }
    usleep(100000);
  }
}

gcc app.c && ./a.out
Counter: 10
Counter: 20
Counter: 30
Counter: 40
Counter: 50
Log size exceeded, rewinding
Counter: 60
Counter: 70
^C

In the LOG, we find expected "out of order" entries:
Log line       58
...
Log line       77
Log line       78
Log line       22
Log line       23
...

Now let's "fix" the app, so it executes some code before rewinding the LOG.
// rewind.c
#define _USE_GNU

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*PFN)(FILE *);

void rewind(FILE *fp)
{
  static PFN pfn;
  if (pfn == NULL) pfn = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "rewind");

  fprintf(stderr, "saving LOG before rewind\n");
  // insert code to upload the LOG here.

  // Now actually rewind the file.
  return pfn(fp);
}

gcc -fPIC -shared -o rewind.so rewind.c
LD_PRELOAD=./rewind.so ./a.out
Counter: 10
Counter: 20
Counter: 30
Counter: 40
Counter: 50
Log size exceeded, rewinding
saving LOG before rewind
Counter: 60
Counter: 70
Counter: 80
Counter: 90
Counter: 100
Counter: 110
Log size exceeded, rewinding
saving LOG before rewind
Counter: 120
Counter: 130
Counter: 140
^C

Voilà.
P.S. The rewind.c may not work for your app if it uses fseek instead of rewind, or if it doesn't use stdio at all.
But you should be able to adjust it -- the idea should work.
